# Passing props between components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component called DatePickerComponent.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {DatePicker} from 'native-base';

export default class DatePickerComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { chosenDate: new Date() };
        this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
    }
        render() {
        return (
         <DatePicker
          defaultDate={new Date()}
          minimumDate={new Date()}
          onDateChange={this.setDate} />)
        }
}
```

I import DatePicker component in Parent.js component , and also need the values changes in DatePicker component . how can i get the values using props ?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePickerComponent from '../../components/DatePicker';

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
 
     render() {return (<DatePickerComponent/>)}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the dateChangeHandler function as prop from the parent component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePickerComponent from '../../components/DatePicker';

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleDateChanges(date){
       console.log(date);
    }

 
     render() {
      return (
        <DatePickerComponent
          onDateChange={this.handleDateChange}
        />
      )
     }

}
```

DatePicker has a `onDateChange` event which provides `date` in its arguements, so the child component can be updated as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {DatePicker} from 'native-base';

export default class DatePickerComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { chosenDate: new Date() };
        // this.setDate = this.props.onDateChange.bind(this);
    }

     handleDateChange(date){
         this.props.onDateChange(date);
    }
        render() {
        return (
         <DatePicker
          defaultDate={new Date()}
          minimumDate={new Date()}
          onDateChange={(date) => this.handleDateChange(date)}
         />
        )
        }
}
```

Comment: I want the values in parent(Parent.js) component from child(DatePickerComponent.js) .

Answer (score 0):

For me it works something like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {DatePicker} from 'native-base';

export default class DatePickerComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
           chosenDate: new Date() 
        };
        this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleDateChange = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
      //send state to parent if needed  
      this.props.handleDate(itemValue);
      this.setState({chosenDate: itemValue})
    }
        render() {
          return (
            <DatePicker
            date={this.state.chosenDate}
            //defaultDate={new Date()}
            //minimumDate={new Date()}
            onDateChange={this.handleDateChange}
          />
         )
        }
}
```

Parent component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePickerComponent from '../../components/DatePicker';

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
    }
    handleDate = (itemValue) => {
      this.setState({date: itemValue});
    }
   }
     render() {
        return (
          <DatePickerComponent
             handleDate={this.handleDate}
          />
    )}
}
```